# How to open .Srt subtitle in media player in c#?

Tags: c#, subtitle

I've created a media player using com components.and it dose not show subtitle of a movie.I used directvobsub but it didn't worked.I wanna to be able to show subtitles without another program. please help.

Comment: whats your code? whats your try result?

Comment: I did not try anyrhing.